# Eclipse Git nested repositories not found

Tags: eclipse, git, repository

I have a project with nested Git repositories which are not detected by Eclipse Mars. I tried to add them manually, but Eclipse is not finding any of the sub repositories even if I point them out.

The sub Gits are created with composer install --prefer-source.
Cli Git works like a charm...

Anyone with the same issue?

Comment: Are these git submodules?

Comment: Try egit, it might work.  Though I fear that the eclipse git tooling is not going to do it for you

Comment: Try adding them as submodules. Select `Add submodule` in repository context menu.

Comment: Is the project checked out into the workspace or outside the workspace? There are some problems with having nested anything inside the workspace.

Comment: Cannot add a submodule, because eclipse says "Path must be empty or non-existent directory".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Eclipse Neon everything is working fine.